# Django custom User and Super User Model

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-users

I have a Django project in which I need a custom user, I followed the steps of [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) to achieve a custom User but Super User shares the same properties. I really dont need those for my admin users. Is there a way to have a specific Model for Admins and Users?

Answer (score 0):

Here as you can see, Django user has  two property `is_staff` and `is_superuser`, admin users should have value `True` for those property(like: `user.is_superuser=True`) and normal users can have it `False`, that can distinguish Admins from Users, other properties like first_name, last_name etc can be shared by both parties.

Otherwise, you can add your own property: ex:

```
class SomeUser(User):
    is_admin= models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

or like:

```
class SomeUser(models.Model):
     user=models.OneToOneField(User)
     is_admin= models.NullBooleanField(default=False, null=True)
     #I prefer like this way of using customizing authentication
```